# Python serial fails 'Inappropriate ioctl for device'

Tags: python, linux, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm running Ubuntu Linux under Windows (WSL) and trying to access the serial port from Python. Reads and writes work successfully. When I try to `send_break` the call fails.

```py
xxxx@yyyyyyyyyy:~$ python
Python 2.7.15+ (default, Jul  9 2019, 16:51:35)
[GCC 7.4.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import serial
>>> ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyS1', timeout=1)   # timeout to make sure read() will actually return
>>> ser.write("Hello!\n")
7
>>> # That call succeeded just fine.
...
>>> ser.read(10)
''
>>> # Nothing returned, but the call was successful
...
>>> ser.send_break()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/xxxx/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 613, in send_break
    termios.tcsendbreak(self.fd, int(duration / 0.25))
termios.error: (25, 'Inappropriate ioctl for device')
>>>
```

This feels like it's probably a bug with the Python module or the Linux driver... is it? Is there any reasonable way I can fix this issue, and successfully send a break over the serial port from Linux running under WSL?

Comment: Looks like an issue with your driver, what UART type is your `/dev/ttyS1`?

Comment: @MarcosG. It's just the native PC COM1 port. I'm guessing you're looking for the actual device driving the port? How do I find that out?

Comment: In case it's helpful: I also grabbed a USB-to-serial converter and tried running that (it was `/dev/ttyS5`). Encountered the exact same problem -- `write()` and `read()` work just fine, but `send_break()` still fails with the "inappropriate ioctl" message.

Comment: What comes out if you do `dmesg | grep /dev/ttyS*`?

Comment: I think this might somehow related to WSL, or at least it works on native Linux for most drivers I've seen

Comment: @MarcosG. If I do `dmesg | grep /dev/ttyS*`, I get nothing at all. It just sits there. To be sure, I tried running `dmesg | grep /dev/ttyS*` while I was accessing the serial port via Python in another terminal, and still nothing. If I run `dmesg` all by itself, the only response is `[    0.005511]  Microsoft 4.4.0-17763.379-Microsoft 4.4.35`.